Pandas count number of specific columns that match certain conditions
I am working on figuring out how to count number of specific columns that match certain conditions and filtering any above 1. I am thinking it would require adding an additional column that includes the count(), and then a separate step of seeing if the count() is greater than 1. Finally, removing the unnecessary count() column.
For the example below, I am interested in only colB, colC, colD, and colE greater than 0.
The example attempted code I have tried looks like:
#Step a
filtData['countCol'] = filtData[(filtData['colB']>0) & (filtData['colC']>0) &
        (filtData['colD']>0) & (filtData['colE']>0)].count()
#Step b
filtData['countCol'] = filtData[filtData['countCol'] > 1]

#Step c
filtData = filtData.drop(columns=['countCol'])

Input:
    colA    colB    colC    colD    colE    colF
0   1105    0.00    867     3.4     0.00    text1
1   1106    3       3.22    1       3       text2
2   1107    0.5     0       0       1       text3
3   1110    0       23      0       0       text4
4   1019    9       0.0     2       0       text5
5   1267    0       0.0     0       2       text6

Output Step a:
    colA    colB    colC    colD    colE    colF    countCol
0   1105    0.00    867     3.4     0.00    text1   2
1   1106    3       3.22    1       3       text2   4
2   1107    0.5     0       0       1       text3   2
3   1110    0       23      0       0       text4   1
4   1019    9       0.0     2       0       text5   2
5   1267    0       0.0     0       2       text6   1

Output Step b:
    colA    colB    colC    colD    colE    colF    countCol
0   1105    0.00    867     3.4     0.00    text1   2
1   1106    3       3.22    1       3       text2   4
2   1107    0.5     0       0       1       text3   2
4   1019    9       0.0     2       0       text5   2

Output Step c:
    colA    colB    colC    colD    colE    colF
0   1105    0.00    867     3.4     0.00    text1
1   1106    3       3.22    1       3       text2
2   1107    0.5     0       0       1       text3
4   1019    9       0.0     2       0       text5

If there is a way to perform this in one step that is elegant (isn't too advanced of an expression to understand), that would be ideal. I am still learning pandas, so maybe performing the filtering I am looking for would need to be broken in the three sub-steps shown.

You can filter columns by list, comapre by 0 abd count Trues by sum, last filter rows greater like 1 in boolean indexing:
out = filtData[(filtData[['colB','colC','colD','colE']]>0).sum(axis=1) > 1]

Or is possible use DataFrame.gt for greater:
out = filtData[filtData[['colB','colC','colD','colE']].gt(0).sum(axis=1).gt(1)]


print (out)
   colA  colB    colC  colD  colE   colF
0  1105   0.0  867.00   3.4   0.0  text1
1  1106   3.0    3.22   1.0   3.0  text2
2  1107   0.5    0.00   0.0   1.0  text3
4  1019   9.0    0.00   2.0   0.0  text5

How it working:
print (filtData[['colB','colC','colD','colE']].gt(0))
    colB   colC   colD   colE
0  False   True   True  False
1   True   True   True   True
2   True  False  False   True
3  False   True  False  False
4   True  False   True  False
5  False  False  False   True

print (filtData[['colB','colC','colD','colE']].gt(0).sum(axis=1))
0    2
1    4
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    1
dtype: int64

print (filtData[['colB','colC','colD','colE']].gt(0).sum(axis=1).gt(1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool


jezrael, would using the dataframe gt() be any quicker in performance for larger data sets? (1M to 26M datapoints and rows)

@Screamcheese I test with 400000 rows with output `%timeit filtData[filtData[['colB','colC','colD','colE']].gt(0).sum(axis=1).gt(1)]
95 ms ± 2.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit filtData[(filtData[['colB','colC','colD','colE']]>0).sum(axis=1) > 1]
90.2 ms ± 269 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

jezrael, thank you! both solutions works well. boolean indexing ftw :)

condition = 0

def assign_count(x):
    count = 0
    if x['colB'] > condition:
        count += 1
    if x['colC'] > condition:
        count += 1
    if x['colD'] > condition:
        count += 1
    if x['colE'] > condition:
        count += 1
    return count

filtData['countCol'] = filtData.apply(assign_count, axis=1)


similarly you can do it for condition=1

apply is really slow here, best is avoid it, because loop under the hood. Vectorized solution is faster (90-95ms), your apply solution is slow(9.78s). So it means 9780/90=108 times slowier.
